# Cannot set property of undefined when set class value

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, class

This is my code, I had tried to set class value to db.db('mydb') to using in other function below

```
class Database {
    constructor() {
        this.db_url = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/";
        let mongodb = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
        mongodb.connect(this.db_url, { useUnifiedTopology: true }, function(err, db) {
            if (err) throw err;
            this.dbo = db.db('mydb');
        })

    }
}
```

I tried to set dbo value of class = db.db('mydb') but I recieved this error

```
            this.dbo = db.db('mydb')
                     ^
TypeError: Cannot set property 'dbo' of undefined
```

but when i append `console.log(db.db('mydb'))` it still print out normally

Answer (score 1):

As the error said: `TypeError: Cannot set property 'dbo' of undefined`, `this` is undefined in your callback function. What I understand is because the "context" is changed (you're in the callback function), `this` is no longer the same thing when you are in the constructor. You can refer to [this popular answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback) for a formal explanation.

In your case, you can use a variable to hold the value of `this`

```
class Database {
    constructor() {
        this.db_url = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/";
        var self = this; // add variable self which refer to the same object with this
        let mongodb = require("mongodb").MongoClient;
        mongodb.connect(this.db_url, { useUnifiedTopology: true }, function(err, db) {
            if (err) throw err;
            self.dbo = db.db('mydb'); // replace this by self
        })

    }
```